# Cannot create CIAreaMinimum and CIAreaMaximum filters

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I am trying to create CIAreaMinimum and CIAreaMaximum CIFilter instances using the following initializers:

```
var minFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaMinimum")
var maxFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaMaximum")
```

These function calls return "nil". I can create other CIFilter instances. Ex: CIColorControls, CIPhotoEffectFade, CIColorInvert, etc..

Has anybody faced this issue? Any help/clues are appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not even bothering to look at the documentation.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAreaMinimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that CIAreaMinimum and CIAreaMaximum exist on OS X only - and you are running on iOS. So those filters rightly return `nil` to indicate that they don't exist.